# JodaTime - Check if LocalTime is after now and now before another LocalTime

Tags: java, android, time, jodatime

I am trying to check if the currenttime is after a start`LocalTime` and before another end`LocalTime` which is the start time plus 11 hours. This works fine if the start time is 11:00 (end time will be 22:00). However when I try to compare a start time of 16:00 and an end time of 03:00, `currentTime.isBefore(endTime)` will never be logged, but it should be.

```
LocalTime currentTime = LocalTime.now(); //21:14
LocalTime startTime = new LocalTime( 16, 00, 0, 0);
LocalTime endTime = startTime.plusHours(11); //03:00 Midnight

    if(currentTime.isAfter(startTime)){
        Log.v("Test", "After startTime");
    }

    if(currentTime.isBefore(endTime)){
        Log.v("Test", "Before endTime");
    }
```

Any ideas how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Basically you need to check whether your `startTime` and `endTime` are inverted (i.e. if `endTime` is before `startTime`). If it is, that must be a "night-time" interval, and you should just treat it as if they were the other way round, and invert the result.

```
public boolean isWithinInterval(LocalTime start, LocalTime end, LocalTime time) {
    if (start.isAfter(end)) {
        return !isWithinInterval(end, start, time);
    }
    // This assumes you want an inclusive start and an exclusive end point.
    return start.compareTo(time) <= 0 &&
           time.compareTo(end) < 0;
}
```

Now the only oddity here is that as shown, the start time is normally inclusive and the end time is exclusive - whereas if we invert the result (and arguments) we have an inclusive end time and an exclusive start time. So you might want to handle the cases explicitly instead:

```
public boolean isWithinInterval(LocalTime start, LocalTime end, LocalTime time) {
    if (start.isAfter(end)) {
        // Return true if the time is after (or at) start, *or* it's before end
        return time.compareTo(start) >= 0 ||
               time.compareTo(end) < 0;
    } else {
        return start.compareTo(time) <= 0 &&
               time.compareTo(end) < 0;
    }
}
```

(How you choose which target and argument you use for `compareTo` is up to you, of course. There are multiple ways of writing effectively the same code.)

Short but complete example:

```
import org.joda.time.LocalTime;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LocalTime morning = new LocalTime(6, 0, 0);
        LocalTime evening = new LocalTime(18, 0, 0);
        LocalTime noon = new LocalTime(12, 0, 0);
        LocalTime midnight = new LocalTime(0, 0, 0);
        System.out.println(isWithinInterval(morning, evening, noon)); // true
        System.out.println(
            isWithinInterval(morning, evening, midnight)); // false
        System.out.println(
            isWithinInterval(evening, morning, noon)); // false
        System.out.println(
            isWithinInterval(evening, morning, midnight)); // true
    }

    public static boolean isWithinInterval(LocalTime start, 
                                           LocalTime end,
                                           LocalTime time) {
        if (start.isAfter(end)) {
            // Return true if the time is after (or at) start,
            // *or* it's before end
            return time.compareTo(start) >= 0 ||
                time.compareTo(end) < 0;
        } else {
            return start.compareTo(time) <= 0 &&
                time.compareTo(end) < 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Any idea how I would implement this?

Comment: Thank you for your effort but both of your methods seem to return false, even if the `currentTime` is before `endTime` but I see why this doesn't work now.

Comment: @Jef: Oops - I had my `if` statement condition the wrong way round. It works now.

Comment: You are awesome, thanks a lot for your effort, you are making me save a lot of time! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

`LocalTime` is exactly that – a **time**.
It doesn't store a date, so your question is fundamentally impossible.

If you want to count hours as they wrap around days, you need to get a date as well, and you need to beware of DST.

Comment: No way, I have been told I should use LocalTime in another question, been changing my code all around until I ran into this problem.

Comment: Thanks for your input anyway, but date will be bound to a specific dat, isn't there any solution where I can just compare times with eachother?

Comment: @Jef: That doesn't make any sense.  How are you supposed to know whether `03:00` is the previous day or the next day?

Comment: I do not need to know, it is impossible for the `endTime` to be before the `startTime` because I will always be adding 11 hours to the `startTime`.

Comment: @SLaks: Because there's a start/end time. So if a shift starts at 4pm and ends at 5am, that would include 3am... but if a shift starts at 5am and ends at 4pm, that wouldn't. It's a reasonably common way of representing things.

Comment: @Jef: No, `endTime` may well be before `startTime` - if you add 11 hours to 5pm (for example) you get 4am, which *is* earlier than 5pm.

Comment: @JonSkeet: Then his API is extremely confusing.  He should have a start & duration instead of a start & an end.

Comment: @SLaks: I don't see it as particularly confusing. In the real world, if a night-shift worker said they were working "10pm until 6am" would you find that confusing?