# How to check Date timestamp occurrence in the time interval

Tags: java, android

I have two `MyDate` objects.

```
class MyDate {

    public int hours, minutes;

    MyDate(int hours, int minutes) {
        this.hours = hours;
        this.minutes = minutes;
    }
}

MyDate startTime;
MyDate endTime;
```

and i have a timestamp as a third MyDate object.

```
MyDate currentTime;
```

I want to know is currentTimeStamp included or not in interval **endDate - startDate**

```
[------------[startTime]------------[currentTime]-----------------[endTime]--------------]
```

I see three combinations of time :

- 23:00 - 08:00 **(07:00 - true)**
- 12:00 - 13:00 **(07:00 - false)**
- 23:59 - 23:58 **(07:00 - true)**

*Explain third case :*

```
[-----------------(23:59)(00:00 - new Day)--(07:00)----------(23:58)--(00:00 - new Day)]
```

How i can check is currentTimeStamp included or not in interval **endDate - startDate**?

Comment: Is there a reason you are not using a well-tested time library like Jodatime, and implementing your own dates instead?

Comment: @Afforess i want implement this withour any third party libraries. This is a alghorithmic issue.

Comment: To figure out if a time is inside an interval you need to check if first if the date is _after_ the start time and _before_ the end time. If both conditions are true, then the date is inside the interval. Create two methods, one to check whether a time is before another time, and the other to check if a time after another time, then the problem becomes simple.

Comment: @Afforess Reproduce this in code. Give me example.

Comment: Can you use Java 8? This is now built-in.

Comment: Is this a homework assignment? If not, rolling your own date-time library is an unwise waste of your time. Search on "Joda" or "java.time".

Comment: Regarding Afforess’ comment, a better way to define and compare spans of time is with the **"Half-Open" approach**. This means the beginning is *inclusive* while the ending is *exclusive*. So comparison operators are `>=` and `<`. Search StackOverflow for "half-open" to learn more.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java: how do I check if a Date is within a certain range?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/494180/java-how-do-i-check-if-a-date-is-within-a-certain-range)

Comment: Just noticed you want time-only comparisons without date portion. Search for "LocalTime". For example, this [Question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22310329).

Answer (score 0):

Reposting my comment, with solution included.

To figure out if a time is inside an interval you need to check if first if the date is *after* the start time and *before* the end time. If both conditions are true, then the date is inside the interval. Create two methods, one to check whether a time is before another time, and the other to check if a time after another time, then the problem becomes simple.

```
class MyDate {
    public int hours, minutes;

    MyDate(int hours, int minutes) {
        this.hours = hours;
        this.minutes = minutes;
    }

    public boolean isBefore(MyDate date) {
        if (date.hours < hours) {
            return true;
        }
        if (date.hours == hours) {
            return date.minutes < minutes;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public boolean isAfter(MyDate date) {
        if (date.hours > hours) {
            return true;
        }
        if (date.hours == hours) {
            return date.minutes > minutes;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public static boolean isBetween(MyDate intervalStart, MyDate intervalEnd, MyDate time) {
        return time.isAfter(intervalStart) && time.isBefore(intervalEnd);
    }
}
```

Really though, time and date code like this should not exist out of homework exercises. There are a vast amount of edge-cases when dealing with dates and times, and they are better left to well-tested libraries, like JodaTime.

Comment: This code doesn't worked on time 23:00 - 08:00 with timestamp 07:00

Comment: Right, because your time spans 2 days, which you can not represent with only hours and minutes. This is exactly why you should leave implementations of date/time code to well-tested libraries.